# Set cookie on browser with node js

Tags: node.js, cookies, browser

I'm quite new to node js and I've encountered a problem with cookies on my client side browser.

So to resume, I am trying to set cookie to a page (which is not yet opened) with node http server, my goal is that I set cookie to this page, then open this URL with node (opn module) and then this page access cookie with document.cookie.

Also, the URL I'm opening is hosted on the node server (localhost/mail/sendingMail/index.html) on port 32126.

I've tried a lot of module and request but couldn't find one that did the job, is this possible and if so, how?

If this isn't possible any way of sending data to this page would be nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have to use [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) for this i also use redis and it is veryfast because it store data on RAM.
in redis you can store objects or hashes or arrays and it is very easy to use with node by installing  [redis-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis)

this is the [best dock](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-redis-node-js/) which i prefer and describe how to use redis with node but remember you have to install redis first .

about redis :-
Redis is an open source (BSD licensed), in-memory data structure store, used as a database, cache and message broker. It supports data structures such as strings, hashes, lists, sets, sorted sets with range queries, bitmaps, hyperloglogs and geospatial indexes with radius queries. Redis has built-in replication, Lua scripting, LRU eviction, transactions and different levels of on-disk persistence, and provides high availability via Redis Sentinel and automatic partitioning with Redis Cluster.